# Playing Gothic 2 without playing first chapter

Tags: gothic-2

I'm going to buy Gothic 2 but I didn't play the first chapter. Is this doable? Will I miss a lot? Would you suggest me to play the first chapter before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't play the first part.

A lot people (like Bobby) think that the first part has more atmosphere, so to get a better whole picture of the series I would play the first part first.

But for me playing only the second part (had a new computer, wanted to play a new game...) was absolutely ok - there were no big gaps in the story.

If your intent is to play the whole series: start with the beginning as the story is continued through the games.

Comment: In the story not, but in the identification with the people from the world there, and this would be for me the reason to play it. It feels much more atmospheric if you know the characters and their story from G1. :)

Answer (score 7):

You mean the first Game, Gothic?

Well, you're gonna miss something of the background and backstory. But as far as I remember, the world is still somekind of self-explaining. But it is heavily building upon the first part, yes. I'd suggest you play that one first.

I also liked the first one more, it seemed a lot more intense and atmospheric then the second.

Answer (score 4):

Gothic 1 has the (little) better atmosphere and story in my opinion (this is maybe because of my memories back in my childhood).

Gothic 2 has a better gameplay, but a little lesser atmosphere (compared to G1 - my opinion) and also a great story. It also has the best fighting-system I ever met in a RPG.

You will meet a lot of friends from G1, so I would recommend to play G1 first. I've played both multiple times.

Comment: Why are you mentioning the fighting system as specific to Gothic 2? The new control scheme for fighting was pretty much the same as Gothic 1 if you chose the classic control scheme. The new control scheme was different, but I liked it less. But it's been a few years since I played Gothic, so I might misremember.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: The fighting system was basically the same, thats true, but there where some small improvements in G2 + fighting didn't work very smooth in G1. You have another way of skilling in G2. In G1 you learn to swing a weapon with only 2 perks (for agility, not for more damage), the the damage is multiplied with your strength and that's it. In G2 you could raise a skill for fighting, the higher it gets (in %), the more agile/fast you are and you have an even higher chance to land a critical hit (which doesn't exist in G1). :)